# SQL What is the Purpose of 1 to 1 self reference on primary key?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I've been tasked with taking over the development of a code base, part of which contains a database for an e-commerce site.

One very interesting pattern I have noted is the author of this DB chose in many cases to self reference tables via the primary key (1 to 1 relationship).

Scripting one of these tables for example, gives the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Address](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [int] NULL,
    [Street] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [Address2] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Zip] [nchar](10) NULL,
    .
    .
    .
CONSTRAINT [PK_Address_Main] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Address]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Address_Address] FOREIGN KEY([ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Address] ([ID])
```

Now I can't for the life of me think of a reason that someone would do this. Let alone make it a pattern for nearly every table in the DB.  So I thought I would throw this out there and ask if anyone has seen this and/or is there some scenario this would support? What does it buy you?

I feel like I can probably drop these 1 to 1 self references on the primary key without consequence.  The code base is largely based off of entity framework from various .net versions.  I just want to make sure I'm not ignorant of some neat trick being done here and there by shooting myself in the foot by dropping these references.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: My thought is drop, I can't see any valid use for it...curious what the community consensus is.  Most likely the previous DB has a very specific use case for it, turned that into a template, and then used that template to create all the rest of the tables.

Comment: @Twelfth Or quite likely through cack handed use of the SSMS foreign keys dialogue.

Comment: Well it would appear that I have consensus and sure enough this question was asked before and agrees with everyone, so I would say we have an answer.  Thanks for the replies. Though I think I asked the question better :P